# ColorFunction in Histogram[]

Tags: color, histograms

Let's say I have a `Histogram`:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500]]
```

[image: Histogram]

and I want the bars positioned to the left of 8 on the horizontal axis to be a different colour.

The *Mathematica* documentation shows how to do this for the height of bars, but not for their position:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500], 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[# < 40, Yellow, 40 <= # < 90, Red, True, Blue] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Histogram2]

How do I call the positions of the bars from Histogram and put them into my `ColorFunction`?

Comment: You will probably need to get the bin data with `HistogramList` and plot it with `BarChart` -- I don't have `HistogramList` in v7 or I'd make this an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a custom `ChartElementDataFunction` as follows:

```
cedF[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :={If[xmax <= 8, 
      RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Sequence[]],
   Dynamic@EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[.015], Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]],
   Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> 5]};
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500],ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartElementFunction -> cedF]
```

[image]

EDIT: Adding arguments to `cedf`:

```
cedf2[from_,to_,color_: Red, t_:Small, rr_: 0][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :=
 {If[from < xmax <= to, color, Sequence[]],
   Dynamic@EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[t], Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]],
   Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> rr]}

 Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
   ChartElementFunction -> cedf2[6, 10, Purple, Small, 3]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can build a custom data function using the built-in `ChartElementDataFunctions`:

```
sgmntsclF = ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleRectangle", 
    "Segments" -> 8, "ColorScheme" -> "TemperatureMap"];
grdntrctF = ChartElementDataFunction["GradientRectangle", 
    "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow", "GradientOrigin" -> Top];

Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500], ChartStyle -> "Pastel",
 ChartElementFunction -> ((If[7 < #[[1, 2]] <= 10, sgmntsclF[##], grdntrctF[##]]) &)]
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't think of this approach. Slick!

Comment: Great. If I wanted to generalise this, how would I go about doing it? i.e. instead of just specifying that bins to the left of X should be red, what about a list specifying a separate colour for each bin?

Comment: Ooku, the simplest way would be using `ChartStyle->{{color1,color2,...}}` which colors each bar with the corresponding color in the list. If the list of colors is shorter than the number of bins, it cycles through the colors. For example: `Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500], 
 ChartStyle -> {ColorData["Atoms", "ColorList"][[;; 70]]}]`. If you need a more general version of `cedf2` that accepts a list of triples `{{from1,to1,color1},{from2,to2,color2}...}` I will update with an example of how it can be done.

Comment: @kglr wow! can you explain the input of cedF[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] function ? What is `___` ?

Comment: @user305883, [BlankNullSequence  (___)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) stands for  any sequence of zero or more  arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You will probably need to get the bin data with HistogramList and plot it with BarChart.

I don't have HistogramList in v7, but here is a basic proof of concept:

```
hist = Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500]]

Cases[hist, RectangleBox[{a_, _}, {b_, x_}] :> {b, x}, -1];

If[# <= 8, Style[#2, Red], #2] & @@@ %;

BarChart @ %
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I'm flying blind here as I can't test this, but maybe it works:

```
dat = HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500]];

If[# <= 8, Style[#2, Red], #2] & @@@ Transpose @ dat;

BarChart @ %
```

Comment: The Cases[] bit doesn't work for me (v8), can you explain what the -1 at the end is doing?

Comment: @Ooku I was afraid there was too much change between versions. :-/  `-1` in `Cases` just specifies searching for the pattern all the way to the bottom level.  Apparently `RectangleBox` is either no longer used, or used with a different syntax.  Cases should return a list of the right $x$ coordinate and top $y$ coordinate for each bar, e.g. `{{3, 1}, {5, 4}, {6, 7}, {7, 24}, {8, 47}, {9, 86}, {10, 95}, {11, 94}, {12, 71}, {13, 37}, {14, 25}, {15, 6}, {16, 3}}`

Comment: @Ooku I think this would be similar to `HistogramList[ . . . ] // Transpose` -- please try that.

Comment: @Ooku I added some code for you to try.