# Colours in BarChart[]

Tags: plotting, charts

This question is a follow up from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11642/colorfunction-in-histogram). I want to be able to specify a list of colours for my bars in `BarChart`. In responses to the question I linked to, @kguler produced the following, which sets the bars to the left of x=8 as a different colour:

```
cedF[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :={If[xmax <= 8, 
   RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Sequence[]],
  Dynamic@EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[.015], Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]],
 Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> 5]};

Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500],ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartElementFunction -> cedF]
```

[image: kguler example]

My question is how to generalise this: I would like to be able to have a list that specifies the colours of every bin uniquely. How would I go about this? If[] statements seem a bit clunky for this application.

Comment: You might take a look at `Which[]` and `Switch[]`.

Comment: ...or `Piecewise[]`. Look at `ChartStyle` as well.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. and VLC, that's helpful. It's silly how all my problems involve not knowing the fundamental functions, but I guess that's life for a Mathematica newbie.

Comment: @Ooku: there's a lot to gain from browsing the docs. In particular, whenever you want to know if something can be done with a function, look at the doc pages for the function itself, as well as the options that seem relevant to what you want to do. Since you're dealing with `BarChart[]`, you could have looked at the options that contained the words `Chart` or `Style` in them...

Comment: Yes, that's clear now. I was looking for a complicated solution when there was a simple one right under my nose! So I guess my question was not only "RTFM", but "XY" also :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a modification of the custom function `cedf2` that accepts a list of `{from,to,color}` triples:

```
ClearAll[cedf3];
cedf3[args : {{_, _, _} ..}, dfltClr_: Red,thcknss_: Small,rndngrds_: 0][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :=
 With[{clr = Function[{lst, xxx},
    With[{pick = Pick[lst, #[[1]] < xxx <= #[[2]] & /@ lst]}, 
     If[pick == {}, dfltClr, Last @@ pick]]][args, xmax]}, {clr, 
 Dynamic@EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[thcknss], Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]], 
 Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> rndngrds]}]
```

(I am sure there is better/shorter way using `Which`, `Switch`, `Piecewise` to pick the bin color instead of the clunky one above using `Pick`)

Update: A cleaner version using `Piecewise`:

```
ClearAll[cedf4];
cedf4[args : {{_, _, _} ..}, dfltClr_:Red,thcknss_:Small, rndngrds_: 3][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :=
{Piecewise[Map[{#[[3]], #[[1]] < xmax <= #[[2]]} &, args], dfltClr],
 Dynamic@EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[thcknss], Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]],
 Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> rndngrds]}
```

Usage: some input data:

```
 binsAndColors1 = Transpose@{Most@Range[0, 50], Rest@Range[0, 50], 
     ColorData["Atoms", "ColorList"][[;; 50]]};
 binsAndColors2 = Transpose@{Most@Range[0, 50, 2], Rest@Range[0, 50, 2], 
     ColorData["Crayola", "ColorList"][[;; 25]]}

Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500], 
  ChartElementFunction -> (cedf3[binsAndColors1, Red, Medium, 3])]
```

[image]

Color consecutive bars with the same color:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 2], 500], 
  ChartElementFunction -> (cedf3[binsAndColors2, Red,Medium, 3])]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `ChartStyle`:

```
 Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500], 
   ChartStyle -> {ColorData["Crayola", "ColorList"][[;; 70]]}]
```

[image]

or, to color neighboring bins with the same color:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500], 
 ChartStyle -> {Riffle[ColorData["Crayola", "ColorList"][[;; 70]], 
    ColorData["Crayola", "ColorList"][[;; 70]]]}]
```

[image]