# Manipulate Histogram

Tags: manipulate, color, histograms

I want to draw a histogram from weighted data, with two sliders to mark a lower and an upper limit on the x-axis. The bins between these two limits should be colored differently from the rest of the plot.
Is it possible to color individual bins in Histogram? Or, alternatively, to use weighted data with BinLists?

Comment: Yes, this is all possible. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html

Comment: Related Q/A: [ColorFunction in Histogram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11646/125)

Comment: Very possible. Having some data and what you have tried would help.