# Coloring the bars greater than a certain value in a histogram

Tags: color, histograms

Given the histogram

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]]
```

is it possible to color the bars that are greater than a certain value, say 0, differently than the bars that are smaller than that value?

Comment: Possible duplicate/closely related Q/A: [ColorFunction in Histogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11642/125)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ideally you could have used the `ColorFunction` option, but sadly for `Histogram` it seems that it only takes the height as an input. You can hack it by combining two histograms:

```
With[{d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]},
 Show[
  Histogram[Select[d, # < 0 &], 
   PlotRange -> {{Min[d], Max[d]}, Automatic}],
  Histogram[Select[d, # >= 0 &], ChartStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A post-processing method:  `Histogram` returns graphics composed of either `Tooltip` + `RectangleBox[]` or simple `Rectangle[]`, depending on how many bins.  So we need a transformation rule for each.

```
rectRule[cf_] := r : Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, opts___] :> {cf[x1, y1, x2, y2], r};
tooltipRule[cf_] := Tooltip[StatusArea[e_, v_], t_] :> 
   With[{color = cf @@ First@Cases[e, 
         RectangleBox[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, opts___] :> {x1, y1, x2, y2}, Infinity]},
    Tooltip[StatusArea[Prepend[e, color], v], t]
    ];
colorize[cf_] := # /. {rectRule[cf], tooltipRule[cf]} &;

(* user color function: color by z-score *)
cf[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] := ColorData[97][Ceiling[Abs[Mean[{x1, x2}]]]];

With[{d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]}, (* yohbs' example *)
    Histogram[d, PlotRange -> {{Min[d], Max[d]}, Automatic}]
  ] /. {rectRule[cf], tooltipRule[cf]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example, showing individual coloring of bin (according to how far from it expected value each is).

```
zscore[x1_, x2_, y2_] := With[{p = Probability[x1 < x < x2, 
      x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]},
   (y2 - 1000 p)/StandardDeviation[BinomialDistribution[1000, p]]];
cf[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_] := 
  ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][Rescale[zscore[x1, x2, y2], {-2.5, 2.5}]];
SeedRandom[2];
With[{d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000], dx = 0.2},
 Legended[
  Show[
   Histogram[d, {dx}, PlotRange -> {{Min[d], Max[d]}, Automatic}] // colorize[cf],
   Plot[dx*1000 PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -3, 3}],
   PlotLabel -> "Variability in sampling"
   ],
  BarLegend[{"RedGreenSplit", {-2.5, 2.5}}, LegendLabel -> "S.D.", LabelStyle -> "Label"]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]